# Android,need to make in my ListView the first letter of each word uppercase

Tags: android

How could i get each word(TextView) in a ListView UpperCase and the rest of the word LowerCase??

Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 5):

in ListView you have methods getCount() and getView(). Using them iterate through the view list, and then do something like:

```
TextView view = listView.getView(...);
String txt = view.getText();
txt = String.valueOf(txt.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + txt.substring(1, txt.length());
view.setText(txt);
```

Don't forget to check for the length of the string you modify.

Comment: use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)

Comment: Thank you for your time,I have a problem with this Line can you explain me what do you mean "TextView view = listView.getView(...);"

Comment: use listView.getChildAt(int) instead of getView().

Answer (score 2):

First letter uppercase and the others lowercase even the String is allready fully uppercased...

```
String text = "text";
String cased = text.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1).toLowerCase();

//STACK/stack/etc. -> "Stack"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String someString = "yourstring";
    String output = someString.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + someString.substring(1);
```

Comment: Thanks goo but if i want in every word from somString how should i do

Answer (score 0):

This should automatically make first character character of each sentence capital in a TextView
*textView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);*

Comment: Ok and how i make the rest of the word lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a help from [`WordUtils.capitalize(sentence)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29) (from apache commons-lang).

Example

```
WordUtils.capitalize("i am FINE") = "I Am FINE"
```

Comment: from where to download this jar for Android ?

Comment: You can download teh jar from http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache//commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang3-3.1-bin.zip

Comment: thanku. I found another link also: http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi