# How to Display First letter of Word capital in to the name android

Tags: android, string

I have name String : abc edf

i want to display fist letter of the all word in capital like : Abc Edf

how to do it ?

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387492/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-title-case-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are many answers to this question. Just for fun I wrote my own method real quick. Feel free to use it and/or improve it:

```
public static String capitalizeAllWords(String str) {
    String phrase = "";
    boolean capitalize = true;
    for (char c : str.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c) && capitalize) {
            phrase += Character.toUpperCase(c);
            capitalize = false;
            continue;
        } else if (c == ' ') {
            capitalize = true;
        }
        phrase += c;
    }
    return phrase;
}
```

Test:

```
String str = "this is a test message";
System.out.print(capitalizeAllWords(str));
```

Output:

```
This Is A Test Message
```

Comment: thank you @Jared Rummler great ans by you +1

Answer (score 1):

Check `org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils`

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html